# Deny a particular user's login

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I have phpmyadmin 3.4 installed on Ubuntu.

Now I simply want to disable a user  (such as `theuser`) logging in through the phpmyadmin page, and in the meantime, allow the user logging in on `localhost`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can find your `config.inc.php` in your installation, under the config for your particular server, add this

```
/* block SOME users */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'deny,allow';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array(
    'deny theuser1 from all',
    'deny theuser2 from all'
);
```

This will disable using phpmyadmin as root,  theuser1 or theuser2. Nothing else changes.

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin after installation, the default is to allow other users to access. On the safe side, you need to set some limits access, to control the access of external users.

Specific modification process is as follows:

1) Open the xampp/apache/conf/extra/HTTPD - xampp. Conf files, search `<LocationMatch` will be the require local is modified to the following code:

```
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.9.25
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

2) Open the \xampp\phpMyAdmin\config inc., PHP, search `Authentication type and info`, is modified to the following values:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '******';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Can also modify the User for the advanced features for the root User.

```
/ * the User for the advanced features * /
The $CFG [' the Servers'] [$I] [' controluser] = 'root';
The $CFG [' the Servers'] [$I] [' controlpass] = '* * * * * *';
```

3) Restart Apache and MySQL service, can test results

Comment: this would allow root access from 192.168.9.25 and localhost, and repeats the mysql root password twice in your config. I think it disables all users except root ?